# Skip random rows from a table

Tags: r, rows, skip

I have a table that has the column header in row 2 with the actual data starting in row 5. My question is how to read the table skipping rows 1, 3 and 4 and assign row 2 as column header?
I'm using something like below. However, would like to understand if there are better ways.

```
headers <- read.table("file_1", skip=1, header=F, sep =',', nrows=1, as.is=T)
df <- read.table("file_1", skip=3, header=F, sep =',')
colnames(df) <- headers
```

Comment: What you've got is probably the best you can do with base R. Other packages may provide more flexibility, but a glance at the `data.table::fread` and `readr::read_table` documentation both make it seem like they expect `skip` to be a single integer.

Comment: If the lines you want to skip all start with a certain character then you could use that...

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas

Answer (score 0):

Not very different, but you could `scan` the header row and `read.table` for the remainder.

You are probably facing something like this.

```
tb <- ' 1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
2  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
4   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
5   5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
6   6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6   6
7   7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7   7
8   8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8   8
9   9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9   9
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  10'
```

`scan` your file, state `what=character()`, how many lines are `skip`ped and `nlines` to read in the column names `r1`. For the data `r2`, `read.table` and `skip=` all unneeded stuff. Skip first element each, since it's the indices. Finally use `r1` to `setNames` of `r2`, and `type.convert`.

```
r1 <- scan(text=tb, what=character(), skip=1, nlines=1)[-1]
r2 <- read.table(text=tb, skip=4)[-1]

res <- r2 |> 
  setNames(r1) |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE)

res
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 1  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
# 2  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6   6
# 3  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7   7
# 4  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8   8
# 5  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9   9
# 6 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  10
```

**Note:** It depends a little on how the data is stored in the file and you probably have to customize the `skip=`'s.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. An useful one indeed.